# How to display a death counter and kill counter on a scoreboard at the same time?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

Well my question is pretty easy to understand. How can I display a players kills and deaths on a scoreboard. I have tried but failed, I know how to make them separate but I can’t get them to both be on at the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This answer may be invalid for console (I didn't know this question was for console until after answering),.

First of all, you need the 2 objectives: Player Kills and Deaths.

This is the command for creating an objective named "Deaths", that will have the death count:

```
/scoreboard objectives add Deaths deathCount
```

And this is the command used to make an objective called "PlayerKills" that will have the player kill count:

```
/scoreboard objectives add PlayerKills playerKillCount
```

You cannot display both objectives on the scoreboard sidebar at the same time, but you can display them at two different places at the same time.

If you have two objectives, you can display one in the `sidebar`, and the other one `belowName` or in the `list`. This is how you display one of the objectives in the sidebar:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay sidebar <objective>
```

This is how you display the objective below a player's name:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay belowName <objective>
```

This is how you display an objective in the list, when you press <kbd>Tab</kbd>:

```
/scoreboard objectives setdisplay list <objective>
```

You can substitute `<objectives>` with either PlayerKills or Deaths, depends which objective you want where.